# Jenkins shows wrong time?

Tags: jenkins

I am running Jenkins on a Linux server and shows the wrong time :(

Situation:
I am running another java app (in tomcat that also runs Jenkins) that shows the correct time in the log files (I use Logback through slf4j).
The bios is set to the UTC time (system clock) like advises here: http://www.linuxsa.org.au/tips/time.html

In Linux it's indicated in /etc/sysconfig/clock that the system clock is set to UTC and in which timezone we are located. I am in UTC+1

Running date command on Linux shows the correct local time. Example:
 Sun Jan  8 12:11:35 CET 2012
But Jenkins shows the time plus 1 hour :(...

The jenkins config shows:
 user.timezone = Europe/Amsterdam (which is UTC+1).

I think that Jenkins (java) thinks the local clock is set to UTC such that 1 hour is added.

How do I solve this?

Comment: This is obviously not a programming question. You should consult serverfault.com

Comment: But then why is it not correct in Jenkins, but does in my own app ? (both java app's). I already triple checked all linux clock settings

Comment: You have an app/admin problem not a programming problem.

Comment: I donno, maybe I need to understand how Jenkins uses his clock such that I can solve it.

Comment: Contact rather the Jenkins mailing list.

Comment: Hmmmm I am confused... as stackOverflow does contains many Jenkins questions, so why not here?...  Just like Hibernate or other technology questions here and not in their mailing list.

Comment: @edbras I'm with you on this. Not sure what the dealio is with the other dude, maybe he's having a bad day & talking it out on you. (I have the same prob' & came here just to also be second-hand rebuffed.) Time & timezone issues with JVM's usually aren't remedied at the OS level, but usually need to be looked at from: the OS setting, the shell env vars, the JVM options, and finally the Java app itself (and remedied using some combination thereof).

Comment: just found on serverfault (dated after this question was asked): http://serverfault.com/questions/406181/how-to-make-jenkins-ci-use-local-time-instead-of-utc-on-debian-squeeze  That being said, the Jenkins site actually says that this solution can cause problems (in certain contexts) and recommends a different option: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Change+time+zone

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Change+time+zone

In short, you can set the system property, either modifying the JVM options,

```
java -Dorg.apache.commons.jelly.tags.fmt.timeZone=TZ ...
```

Or changing Jenkins configuration in /etc/default/jenkins (Debian) or /etc/sysconfig/jenkins (Red Hat):

```
JAVA_ARGS="-Dorg.apache.commons.jelly.tags.fmt.timeZone=America/New_York"
```

It also mentioned `-Duser.timezone="..."` is an option, but can cause problems / interfere with other contexts (some vague hand-waving & caveats: time travel is always unpredictable).

In general (in my experience), don't change the system time, since us, our servers & our data live in a global world & should be handling, sending, comparing all times in UTC until the latest possible moment: usually that's the GUI (presentation layer) just before being displayed (...if even then). (Our build system results actually produces data that is fed into another system in another time zone.)

Comment: We have user.timezone set to the correct timezone, but Jenkins is still using UTC. It turns out that master is set correctly, but the slaves are not. How can the slaves be set to the correct timezone?

Answer (score 19):

If you are running Jenkins with Docker, you can append `-e JAVA_OPTS=-Duser.timezone=TZ` to docker arguments.

```
docker run -e JAVA_OPTS=-Duser.timezone=$TZ jenkins
```

All available `TZ` can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Comment: I have set `ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Duser.timezone=Europe/Rome"` in the Dockerfile, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

On Jenkins 2.63 on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS setting

```
JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Duser.timezone=America/Los_Angeles"
```

in `/etc/default/jenkins` and then doing

```
sudo service jenkins stop
sudo service jenkins start
```

worked for me to change the timezone from UTC to PDT.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in a Dockerfile and it will work;

```
RUN echo "import hudson.model.*;" > 
/var/jenkins_home/init.groovy.d/timezone.groovy && \
echo "import jenkins.model.*;" >> 
/var/jenkins_home/init.groovy.d/timezone.groovy && \
echo "System.setProperty('org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.fmt.timeZone', 
'America/Denver')" >> /var/jenkins_home/init.groovy.d/timezone.groovy
```

$JENKINS_HOME/init.groovy.d/*.groovy will get executed at start up.

```
System.setProperty('org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.fmt.timeZone', 
'America/Denver')
```

That sets the timezone.

Answer (score 0):

For official Jenkins Docker image (lts:2.138.1), you should set Jenkins java options to your local TZ. You can use this env. variable in a docker run command or docker-compose as well.

See here: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Change+time+zone

```
JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Duser.timezone=Europe/Paris"
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you have additional slaves you can sync the clock by using [ntp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol). On Linux you can run following commands for each slave:

```
sudo systemctl stop ntp
sudo ntpdate -qu 0.debian.pool.ntp.org
sudo systemctl restart ntp
sudo systemctl status ntp
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way without restarting Jenkins:

1. Open "Manage Jenkins" -> "Script Console"
2. Run the script:

```
System.setProperty('org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.fmt.timeZone', 'America/New_York')
```